# Proper HTML5 canvas control point

Tags: canvas, equation, graphing

I am playing around with a canvas element and am in need of some assistance with the `quadraticCurveTo` method. I was hoping to reflect the drawing on the canvas to what is displayed on a graphing calculator.

Right now it's currently setup so the control point coordinates are `endpoint_x,start_y`.

Diagram with the start (also the vertex), end, and control points:

```
+------------------+
|                e |
|               .* |
|              . * |
|            .   * |
|          .     * |
|        .       * |
|     .          * |
|  s * * * * * * c |
+------------------+
```

After creating an equation (based off of `y = a(x - h)^2 + k`) and plugging in the equation into my calculator, I am not getting what is reflected on my graph. What is the proper control point for me to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bezier curve is not a function graph/plot. Wikipedia is very good at explaining how they work:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve